# Passing value from one activity to overwrite its value in another

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that takes a string to calculate some algorithms. It works fine.
Now I am trying to call this activity from a main activity, so main activity takes a user input to overwrite the string from the second activity. I have an Editable field in the main activity.I am not able to pass the value from the main activity to the second one. How can I do this?  My code for the main activity looks like this

```
public void onClick(View view){
       switch (view.getid())

    case R.id.calculate:

    setname= insertname.getText.toString(); //insertname is the Editablefield
    Intent i = new Intent(this, themain.class);

    i.putExtra("Name",insertname); //
    startActivityForresult(i,1);

    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onactivityresult(requestcode resultcode data);
    switch (requestcode ){

    case 1:
    //return result form activity 2
    }
    }

// Code for second activity is something like this:

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getid()) {

    case R.id.calculate:
        break;
    /*
     * this bit of code takes a string and gets data for this user and
     * returns it in an array. I am trying to overwrite this string
     */

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to pass the value from the main activity to the second one. How can I do this

Comment: So, are you unable to pass this value of insertname by this i.putExtra("Name",insertname); ?

Comment: You are trying to set the entire view as an extra. That won't work. Just set the content string.

Comment: name your acrivity2 is themain.class ?I think use it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, themain.class);

i.putExtra("Name",setname);  // replace here with setname
startActivityForresult(i,1);
```

Comment: Into your code you are passing the `insertname`, just replace with the `setname`. `insername` is the object of the edittext and `setname` is the value of that edittext.

Comment: have done that, but I still cannot get this to overwite the string in my activity..

Answer (score 0):

you can send your string to activity2 from your activity as following:

```
String str = "My Data"; //Data you want to send
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name",str);
startActivityForresult(i,1);
```

you can receive str in activity2 as following:

```
String name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```